WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE for the headers
WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE    A unique ID to track the consumer request by channel    Yes for V3, optional for V2 0f3e4dd4-0514-4346-b39d-… use the Consumer Channel Type received during onboarding
I am trying access Wallmart's seller api for getting products but I am not able to find  WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE for the headers.

Just found it, in my account > under the api key and consumer ID section

Just found it, in my account > under the api key and consumer ID section
You can see the screenshot for reference
